# How to get simple answer from isolate?

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

I am learning about [`Isolate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html)'s. I read docs. And want to write minimal working example. Here is my code:

```
main() async
 {

  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
  Isolate.spawn(echo, receivePort.sendPort);

  var sendPort = await receivePort.first;

 }


 echo(SendPort sendPort)
 {
   ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();
   sendPort.send(receivePort);
 }
```

It almost ok, but I can't understand how I can send simple "Hello" message back. I looked few examples and there was some middle-ware like `sendReceive()`. Im I right understand that after:

```
var sendPort = await receivePort.first;
```

`sendPort` will store name/address of spawned function and I need `sendPort.send("hello");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already stated how to send simple data using [`SendPort.send`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/SendPort/send.html). In fact, you are only **able to** send *primitive data types*, i.e. `null, num, bool, double, String` as described in the documentation.
I will complete your example in the following.

```dart
import 'dart:isolate';

main() async {
  final receivePort = ReceivePort();
  await Isolate.spawn(echo, receivePort.sendPort);

  final Stream receivePortStream = receivePort.asBroadcastStream();

  receivePortStream.listen((message) {
    if (message is String) {
      print('Message from listener: $message');
    } else if (message is num) {
      print('Computation result: $message');
    }
  });

  final firstMessage = await receivePortStream.first;
  print(firstMessage);
}

echo(SendPort sendPort) {
  sendPort.send('hello');

  sendPort.send('another one');

  final computationResult = 27 * 939;
  sendPort.send(computationResult);
}
```

Note that you want to simply send `'hello'` and not some other `ReceivePort`, which will not even work as it is not a primitive value.
In my example, I also setup another listener that will process further messages.

Additionally, I needed to create the `receivePortStream` variable as a broadcast stream in order to be able to both *listen* to it **and** get the first message. If you try to run `ReceivePort.listen` and `ReceivePort.first` on the same `ReceivePort`, you will get an exception.